# Rounded corners on a rectangle are not even

Tags: inkscape

Inkscape suddenly decided to make rectangle corner rounding uneven. I'm not sure what setting was changed.

Currently two files are open and in file 1 corner rounding is even, while in file 2 corner rounding is uneven. I press the same key combo in both cases (Ctrl + Left Mouse Click and drag).

File 1: even corners
[image: File 1: even corners]
File 2: uneven corners
[image: File 2: uneven corners]

Is this a bug or a setting that got changed inadvertently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two corner radii - Rx, and Ry, and two corner controls on the rectangle. So there are two ways to fix it.

You could simply type in the Rx and Ry boxes, making sure they have the same values.

Or you can use the corner radius controls on the rectangle.  The lower one controls the master (Ry) roundness of both, the upper one adjusts the Rx roundness. If you move this one back to the corner, the other takes over the control of the corner radius.

[image]

If you mess up, there's also a "make corners sharp" button to reset it. Then you can adjust the rounding control again.

[image]

Comment: To complete the list of options: https://inkscape.org/en/doc/keys092.html#idm2597 (keys and mouse reference, section for rounded corners on rectangles)